# Bayesian regression for proportions or rates response variable (0,1) in R

Tags: r, glm, bayesian, bayesglm

I have my response variable as proportions with values between 0 and 1, 0 and 1 not included. I would like to perform Bayesian logit regression. I am using the package `arm` in R and I followed the example in [Bayesian Generalized Linear Models in R](https://it.unt.edu/sites/default/files/bayesglm_jds_jan2011.pdf) as published by Jon Starkweather, PhD. The difficulty or the confusion I have in mind is that with the frequentist glm approach, I could do beta regression (and specify logit link). But when it comes to the Bayesian glm, I am unsure how to specify the link function for this proportions data, especially using the routine provided in the `arm` package and as used in the above cited paper regarding the `Bayesglm` function.
The adapted code I am using is as below:

```
#install.packages("arm")
library(arm)

Model<-bayesglm(y ~x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 
              + x7 + x8 + x9,family = gaussian, data=mydata,prior.mean=0, prior.scale=Inf, prior.df=Inf)
summary(Model)

Call:
bayesglm(formula = y ~x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 
              + x7 + x8 + x9, family = gaussian, data = panel1_neg, prior.mean = 0, 
             prior.scale = Inf, prior.df = Inf)

Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.024267  -0.006407  -0.001379   0.006257   0.042012  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.046806   0.011057   4.233 5.16e-05 ***
       x1      0.327205   0.084408   3.876 0.000191 ***
   I(x1^2)     -1.351503   0.395559  -3.417 0.000921 ***
      x2      -0.333285   0.056133  -5.937 4.30e-08 ***
      x3       0.074882   0.029916   2.503 0.013949 *  
      x4       0.012951   0.003231   4.009 0.000119 ***
      x5      -0.053934   0.059021  -0.914 0.363042    
      x6      -0.082908   0.051511  -1.610 0.110690    
      x7      -0.019248   0.068604  -0.281 0.779623    
      x8      -0.012700   0.002549  -4.981 2.68e-06 ***
      x9       0.006289   0.002575   2.442 0.016382 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.0001288981)

    Null deviance: 0.032699  on 109  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.012761  on  99  degrees of freedom
AIC: -660.64

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

So my question is, how do I specify a logit link in `Bayesglm` function? If the response variable were binary, I could specify `family=binomial(link=logit)`.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about `bayesglm`, but [`rstanarm` has a Beta regression implementation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/betareg.html).

Answer (score 0):

The frequentist / bayesian terminology is a bit too confusing. Basically the question is how to run a binomial regression with either `glm` (from `stats`) or `bayesglm` (from `arm` )

Suppose our dataset is this, different levels of successes associated with different x, and n = 10 :

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(success = c(rbinom(20,10,0.6),rbinom(20,10,0.6)),
x = rep(0:1,each=20))

df$n = 10
```

We calculate the proportion:

```
df$p = df$success / df$n
```

And you regress by using weights:

```
glm(p ~ x,weights=n,family=binomial(link=logit),data=df)

Call:  glm(formula = p ~ x, family = binomial, data = df, weights = n)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.6411      -0.2356  

Degrees of Freedom: 39 Total (i.e. Null);  38 Residual
Null Deviance:      28.33 
Residual Deviance: 27.04    AIC: 137.5
```

Same for bayesglm :

```
bayesglm(p ~ x,weights=n,family=binomial(link=logit),data=df)

Call:  bayesglm(formula = p ~ x, family = binomial(link = logit), data = df, 
    weights = n)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.6394      -0.2325  

Degrees of Freedom: 39 Total (i.e. Null);  38 Residual
Null Deviance:      28.33 
Residual Deviance: 27.04    AIC: 71.04
```

Also check out the [accepted answer for this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386675/what-are-weights-in-a-binary-glm-and-how-to-calculate-them)

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, thanks for your suggestion. But I am not sure if this resolves my problem. I am not running a Bayesian logit model for a binomial distributed dependent variable. My dependent variable is a ```rates``` variable calculated for example as ```a/b ``` where data on ```a``` and ```b``` are not available. So I am not sure what would constitute ```weights``` in this case and how I would use same. My understanding is that such rates variables are beta distributed. In short I am looking for a way to specify the family to be beta and the ```link``` to be ```logit```.